# Error inflating a custom View class

Tags: android

I tried to develop a class `Checkerboard` that extends `View` that displays a checkerboard using `onDrawn` method over a canvas.

However, when I try include it into a layout, Android throws me the following error:

```
07-16 13:26:34.677 2478-2478/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: vmc.chesslys, PID: 2478
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vmc.chesslys/vmc.chesslys.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class vmc.chesslys.CheckerBoard
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class vmc.chesslys.CheckerBoard
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class vmc.chesslys.CheckerBoard
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
                                                 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:618)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                 at vmc.chesslys.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="vmc.chesslys.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <view
        class="vmc.chesslys.CheckerBoard"
        android:id="@+id/chessboard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the main activity wthat inflates it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `CheckerBoard` class lacks a two-parameter `public` constructor taking a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`. This is the constructor used by `LayoutInflater`.